# Add TextView Dynamically To a view Android

Tags: android

I want to display multiple text view in a layout dynamically.
Suppose,User selects 10 items from drop down menu then I can display it to layout one after another.I need same view as attached image - [image]

[image]

I have selected item in a list,now I am not getting how to  display data in desire manner.When I try list view all data are display one after other vertically.
When I use Linearlayout data can be either added in horizontal or vertical order.So I am not getting correct way to display data.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i use grid view there are space for aligning data in it.betweenn columns

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called chips.why not use material design chips, you can refer it here. http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips.html#
 you can implement like using grid view if you are not interested using chips just have one row of gridview and populate it there with one cell

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, it will put your items as you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..i used to acheive using custom view.if you are ok with this just give a try..

Custom View class is.

```
    public class WrapLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private int paddingHorizontal;
    private int paddingVertical;

    public WrapLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public WrapLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public WrapLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paddingHorizontal = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(10);
        paddingVertical = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int childTop = getPaddingTop();
        int lineHeight = 0;
        // 100 is a dummy number, widthMeasureSpec should always be EXACTLY for FlowLayout
        int myWidth = resolveSize(100, widthMeasureSpec);
        int wantedHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                continue;
            }
            // let the child measure itself
            child.measure(
                    getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().width),
                    getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, 0, child.getLayoutParams().height));
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            // lineheight is the height of current line, should be the height of the heightest view
            lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
            if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
                // wrap this line
                childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
                lineHeight = childHeight;
            }
            childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
        }
        wantedHeight += childTop + lineHeight + getPaddingBottom();
        setMeasuredDimension(myWidth, resolveSize(wantedHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int childTop = getPaddingTop();
        int lineHeight = 0;
        int myWidth = right - left;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                continue;
            }
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            lineHeight = Math.max(childHeight, lineHeight);
            if (childWidth + childLeft + getPaddingRight() > myWidth) {
                childLeft = getPaddingLeft();
                childTop += paddingVertical + lineHeight;
                lineHeight = childHeight;
            }
            child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + childWidth, childTop + childHeight);
            childLeft += childWidth + paddingHorizontal;
        }
    }
    }
```

and my xml is :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText_sample"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add It"
        android:id="@+id/addit"
         />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <!-- i mean where you put the WrapLayout class in your project that package name -->
        <your.package.name.WrapLayout
            android:id="@+id/flow_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"/>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And finally in MainActivity

```
        ViewGroup flowContainer;
```

In OnCreate

```
        flowContainer= (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.flow_container);
        final EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_sample);
        Button addIT=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addit);
        addIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data=text.getText().toString();
                flowContainer.addView(createTextView(data),
                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        });
```

Copy this function within mainactivity

```
       private View createTextView(String text) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);                     
         textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.mipmap.ic_launcher,0);
        return textView;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Let i am try it and then reply you.